# creating clustered bar plot from contingency table in R

Tags: r, plot

This is result of a contingency table:

```
rating  high    low medium 
1        158    1    36
2        77     2    25
3        106    10   36
4        82     56   71
5       60      97   62
```

I need to create  a clustered bar plot like this:

[image]
How can I do it ? 
I tried bar plot and ggplot, but they did not work.

Comment: Just dodge the bars. http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with getting it to work with `ggplot` is to realize that you essentially need three pieces of information: 1) `rating`, 2) values of `high`, `medium`, and `low`, and 3) the color that will be used to differentiate. The problem is that the data is not currently in this format. We can use the `gather` function from the `tidyverse` to solve this, and then plot the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat = data_frame(rating=1:5, high=c(158, 77, 106, 82, 60), medium=c(1, 20, 10, 56, 97), low=c(36,25,36,71,62))
dat = dat %>%
    gather(key=color, value=value, -rating)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=rating, y=value, fill=color)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

`gather` basically works by taking a bunch of columns and using the column names as the values the newly created `key` variable (what we're calling color), and the values of those columns as the values in our newly created `value` column (which we call value).

Comment: Trivial point: you have swapped Mary's medium and low numbers, but like Mary your plot comes out  in alphabetical order *high, low,  medium* which I see as sub-optimal

Comment: @Henry ah, yes, it appears I did swap `medium` and `low`. As for getting them in the (presumably) correct order, I didn't view that as the main topic of the question and therefore did not address it. How to reorder bars/colors should be its own question, and one that has undoubtedly already been answered on here.

Comment: @brittneb, Would you please let me know how I can remove the background and also change colors in the plot?